# React MUI Collapse component ignores timeout and acts as if timeout is 0

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm using React, Typescript with MUI and I wanted to make a burger menu where each clicking on an option smoothly opens a `<Box>` component, which contains additional options. What happens is that it ignores the `timeout={2000}` prop and just displays it as if it's `display` is none and then gets turned into `display:block` for example.

```
const [badgeMenuOpen, setBadgeMenuOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);
const [badgeMenuOpen1, setBadgeMenuOpen1] = useState<boolean>(false);
const [badgeMenuOpen2, setBadgeMenuOpen2] = useState<boolean\>(false);

const handleMenuClick = () => {
    if (badgeMenuOpen) {
      setBadgeMenuOpen(false);
    } else {
      setBadgeMenuOpen(true);
    }
};
const handleMenu1Click = () => {
 if (badgeMenuOpen1) {
  setBadgeMenuOpen1(false);
 } else {
  setBadgeMenuOpen1(true);
 }
};

const handleMenu2Click = () => {
 if (badgeMenuOpen2) {
  setBadgeMenuOpen2(false);
 } else {
  setBadgeMenuOpen2(true);
 }
};
```

```
<IconButton
 size="medium"
 edge="start"
 sx={{ color: "#0073d1" }}
 aria-label="sidebar-logo"
 onClick={handleSideMenuClick}
/>
<Typography>menu\</Typography>
<MenuIcon\>
<IconButton\>
<StyledDrawer
 open={sideMenuOpen}
 anchor="right"
 hideBackdrop={true}
 aria-controls={sideMenuOpen ? "sidebar-logo" : undefined}
 aria-expanded={sideMenuOpen ? true : false}
 sx={{ marginTop: "60px", backgroundColor: "#f8f8f" }}
 onClose={() =\> {
  setSideMenuOpen(false);
 }}
 id="MUI-drawer"
\>
<Box minWidth={"100%"} role="presentation"\>
<List
 disablePadding={true}
 sx={{ minWidth: "100%", display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}
\>
<ListItem sx={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}>
<RouterLink
 className="header__phone-menu__item__submenu__item"
 to="/home"
\>
 {t("exampletext")}
</RouterLink\>
<Divider /\>
</ListItem\>
<Divider /\>
<ListItem
 disablePadding={true}
 sx={{
  display: "flex",
  flexDirection: "column",
  backgroundColor: badgeMenuOpen1 ? "#fff" : "#f8f8f",
 }}
\>
 <StyledBadge
  onClick={handleMenu1Click}
  id={"badgeMenu"}
  color="error"
  invisible={false}
  badgeContent={"!"}
  sx={{
   display: "flex",
   flexDirection: "column",
  }}
   className="header__phone-menu__item__submenu-toggle"
 \>
  {t("exampletext")}
 </StyledBadge>
 <Box
  sx={{ height: badgeMenuOpen1 ? "100%" : "0px" }}
  id="badgeId"
  className="header__phone-menu__item__submenu"
 \>
 <RouterLink
  className="header__phone-menu__item__submenu__item"
  to="/cards"
 \>
  {t("exampletext")}
 </RouterLink\>
```

I tried using `<Fade>` component, which actually worked, but it just changed it's opacity to 0 so the space was still occupied and that doesn't quite work for me.

Are there any specific parents that the `<Collapse>` component has to be inside for it to work?

--EDIT-- Ignore the `\` inside the code, stackoverflow formated it somehow

Comment: Hi, your code is a bit hard to read and understand as it is. Could you please edit the post to remove the slashes, put indentation and even put the code in a sandbox so that we can visualise what happens please? Thanks

Comment: the components are from MUI framework so I cannot run it in sandbox